# Is it just me or is the Rocket League's "Super Sonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle Cars" Konami Code easter egg GONE?

Tags: xbox-one, cheats, rocket-league

People say that on the opening screen of Rocket League and you enter the Konami Code (`UP UP DOWN DOWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT B A`) you get the "*Super  Sonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle Cars*" title and possibly a special car.

Is it just me or this is gone from the game? Or am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: I just looked this up and all 3 pages I found said to use a ps4 dualshock controller. I didn't see anything about doing it with a keyboard or xbox controller. (It is also `square` `X` instead of `B` `A`)

Answer (score 2):

I'm skeptical that this will work (see below) but first try adding `Start` at the end of the Konami Code:

`UP UP DOWN DOWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT B A Start`

[(Source)](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/46dxuq/rocket_league_konami_code_easter_egg/)

<s>If that didn't work, try swapping `B` and `A` in the code.  I've read that between PC and PS4, that the `Circle` and `X` in the Konami code switch places (it goes `...Circle X` for PC and `...X Circle` for PS4) so try switching `B` and `A` (`...A B`).  I would try this first without the Start button added at the end, and with the Start button if it didn't do anything.</s>

Also try it while the game is loading up rather than at the start menu.

---

I'm skeptical that the above will work because I've read on multiple websites that the Easter egg is only available on PC and PS4 (in fact, for PC you have to use a Dualshock 4 controller as well). At the least, there is no mentioning about it working for Xbox on these sites:

- [Rocket League Tips](http://rocketleaguetips.net/rocket-league-easter-egg/)
- [Rocket-League.com](https://rocket-league.com/news/rl-easter-eggs-sarpbc-in-rocket-league)
- [Gaming PC Forums](http://www.gamingpcforum.com/konami-code-used-on-rocket-league-to-get-sarpbc-easter-egg/) (they say its only available for PC)

I haven't been able to find any sources supporting that you can do this on Xbox One.

**EDIT:** I've confirmed (now that I own the game on Xbox One) that the above code is in fact what you need to type in while the game is loading (`UP UP DOWN DOWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT B A Start`).

Answer (score 2):

You actually can't get the moai anymore. It's been removed.

Comment: This is correct. See [the wiki](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Moai)

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>UP</kbd> <kbd>UP</kbd> <kbd>DOWN</kbd> <kbd>DOWN</kbd> <kbd>LEFT</kbd> <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> <kbd>LEFT</kbd> <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
Is it on the pc. You will need the enter to work.

Edit: you only get the moai antenne and not a special car.

Comment: Isn't that the same code Timmy Jim has already posted? You should try to add something new to it, if you answer already answered questions.